# How to enable CCSM startup dialog again?

Tags: unity, compiz

I have just installed CCSM to enable wobbly windows. CCSM presented me a dialog with a warning to use the program with caution. Several programs have such dialog, usually with a check box to whether show again or skip the dialog the next time the program starts.

I have disabled the CCSM startup dialog, but now I think it should have been better to have left it activated. It is a very small annoyance, I know, and I don't mind having it the way it is. Nevertheless, I thought it would be nice to know where this setting/flag is saved since I can't find a way to re-activate it from CCSM, and also if the majority of programs have a standard location/way to save that preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compiz store a file called 'firstrun' under the `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig` path. So all you have is to delete this file and then run CCSM again so it will shows you the warning dialog.

```
sudo rm -f ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/firstrun
```

***Tip:*** In general you don't have to use sudo within your home, but here you have to use sudo even in your home dirs since this file and other Default.ini are owned by root.

Comment: Thanks! That did restore the start dialog. Do all the other programs store it in a similar file under .config?